# Userinputs via scanner

Tags: java, math, geometry

I'm trying to make a method which given a radius, tells you the area & circumference of that given circle, though it won't compile, telling me something about missing return-statements.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class circlecalc
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = scanner.nextInt ();
        calc(input);
    }
    public static double calc(double n)
    {
        System.out.print("The area of the circle is: ");
        System.out.println((n*n)*Math.PI);
        System.out.print("The circumference of a circle with that radius is: ");
        System.out.println((n*2)*Math.PI);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are not returning double value in calc method

Comment: The `double` in `public static double calc(double n)` means that the method should return a value of type double. Since your `calc` method has no `return` statement, this cannot be true. If you really want to print everything inside of `calc`, then you should change `double` to `void` meaning you will not return anything from that method.

Comment: *"telling me something about missing return-statements."*  Always copy/paste error & exception output.

Comment: public static void calc(double n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Compile error** appears is that you declare a method like

```
  public static double calc(double n)
```

, which needs a return value but you did not return anything.

I notice that in method **`calc`** is just used to print informaiton, where does not need an return value.

So you can use it like below

```
  public static void calc(double n)
```

rather than

```
  public static double calc(double n) as you declared.
```

Answer (score 0):

the function calc expected to return a double value and so you are getting return statements error

```
public static double calc(double n)
```

Change its return type to void i.e.

```
public static void calc(double n)
```